# Continuous scrolling between two UIPageControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to achieve a continuous scrolling in the following situation:

MainViewController (`UIViewController`) contains an instance of `UIPageViewController` (`transitionStyle: .scroll`) which manages two controllers only; ItemsViewController (`UIViewController`) & ProfileViewController (`UIViewController`). MainViewController allows scrolling between main and profile controllers horizontally.

Now ProfileViewController contains another instance of `UIPageViewController` (`transitionStyle: .scroll`) to scroll horizontally between two `UIViewController`s (A & B).

The issue is that when I scroll to ProfileViewController and start scrolling between A & B then I can't scroll (**to the right**) to go back to ItemsViewController. It seems that the `UIPageViewController` of ProfileViewController is intercepting the scroll gesture and doesn't pass them to `UIPageViewController` instance of MainViewController and you will get stuck in ProfileViewController.

Here is some code:

```
final class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    private let pageController: UIPageViewController
    let itemsController: ItemsViewController
    let profileController: ProfileViewController
    private var controllers = [UIViewController]()
    private(set) var currentPageIndex = 0

    override init(...) {
        itemsController = ItemsViewController(...)
        controllers.append(itemsController)
        profileController = ProfileViewController(...)
        controllers.append(profileController)
        pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        super.init(...)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configurePageController()
    }

    func configurePageController() {
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self
        pageController.setViewControllers([itemsController], direction: .forward, animated: false)

        for view in pageController.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.delegate = self
                break
            }
        }
    }
} 

extension MainViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index > 0 {
                return controllers[index - 1]
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
            if index < controllers.count - 1 {
                return controllers[index + 1]
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        guard completed else {
            return
        }
        if let vc = pageController.viewControllers?.first,
            let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: vc) {
            currentPageIndex = index
        }
    }
}

// Freeze scrolling on the left and right edges 
extension MainViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    private func freezScrolling(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if currentPageIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
        }
        else if currentPageIndex == controllers.count - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        freezScrolling(scrollView)
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        freezScrolling(scrollView)
    }
}
```

```
final class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    private let pageController: UIPageViewController
    private lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = [ControllerA, ControllerB]
    private var currentPageIndex = 0

    override init(...) {
        pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        super.init(...)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configurePageController()
    }

    func configurePageController() {
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        for view in pageController.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.delegate = self
                break
            }
        }
    }

extension ProfileViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index > 0 {
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index < controllers.count - 1 {
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        guard completed else {
            return
        }

        if let vc = pageController.viewControllers?.first,
            let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: vc) {
            currentPageIndex = index
        }
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        freezScrolling(scrollView)
    }

    private func freezScrolling(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if currentPageIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
        }
        else if currentPageIndex == controllers.count - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        freezScrolling(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing... why wouldn't you make this 3 "pages" in one page view controller?

Comment: @DonMag
The page controller inside ProfileViewController just taking 50% of the screen (bottom) as there is another child controller (top), so making them in one pageController violates the design we need to achieve.

Comment: What is `freezScrolling()` supposed to be doing? Does your layout work *without* that?

Comment: This will just stop the page controller from bouncing on the left and right when reaching the first or last controller, the layout works fine without it.

Comment: OK, well that's obviously the issue then. `UIPageViewController` is not designed to not bounce, and searching for solutions results in a lot of comments of "sort-of works but not reliable." As a general rule, users are familiar with scroll view (and page view controller) behavior. If you really want your own custom behavior, you'll likely have to write your own scrolling / page code.